# Installing the pst-optexp package

Tags: pstricks, pst-optexp

I am having trouble installing and using `pst-optex` package. I went through the documentation installed all the prerequisites. But my tex comiler(TeXMaker) keeps giving errors. The code I have written is a simple example code from its documentation.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-0.3)(3,2.3)
\pnodes(0,1){A}(3,1){B}
\lens(A)(B)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

> I get a undefined control sequence error at the line \begin{psp....

Could someone tell me what I could be missing of if there is a exhaustive material on this point me towards that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

first check that you run `xelatex` and *not* `pdflatex`. Then:

for MikTeX: Go into the package manager (via the start button->MikTeX) and install pst-optexp

for TeXLive: do the same as for MikTeX or install it from the terminal: `tlmgr install pst-optexp`

Comment: Happy New Year! Note though, that `xelatex` doesn't work with `pst-optexp`'s beam tracing, but requires `dvips -> ps2pdf`. I have no idea what exactly goes wrong, or how to fix that :(

Comment: @Christoph: send me an example which doesn't work.

Comment: It's example 3 in [Understanding beams in pst-optexp](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219495/33933). That gives a ghostscript error when compiled with `xelatex`. I don't know how to debug such XeLaTeX problems.